# IOT - Error : LEDC is not initialized Nodemcu ESP32 in wokwi

Tags: iot, esp32, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

i am using wokwi for ESP32 simulation and i get error LEDC is not initialized, i am confused which part of my code there is error like that. I attached my code:

```
#define Balarm  13  
#define PIRsensor 2 
#define LedPin 14
#define pitch  262

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(PIRsensor, INPUT); // PIR sensor as input  
  pinMode(Balarm, OUTPUT);   // Buzzer alaram as output
  pinMode(LedPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite (Balarm, LOW);// Initially buzzer off
}

void loop(){
  int state = digitalRead(PIRsensor); 
  delay(500);                         
    if(state == HIGH){                
      tone(Balarm, pitch);   
      digitalWrite (LedPin , HIGH); 
      delay(1000);  
    }
    else {
      noTone(Balarm);    //No intrusion Buzzer off
      digitalWrite (LedPin , LOW);
    }
}
```

I also want to ask why the buzzer sound can't be heard, how to make it sound, shouldn't it just use toner(). I also added an image, and I also want to ask if the flow of my image is suitable for making anti-theft alarms,if the sensor is on then the buzzer and led are also lit.I ask for his help to correct the location of the error I made:

https://ibb.co/6PC18Qz

Answer (score -1):

Sorry that you haven't received a response.

You are using the Arduino tone library. When using the ESP32, you should refer to the [LEDC API](https://espressif-docs.readthedocs-hosted.com/projects/arduino-esp32/en/latest/api/ledc.html).

Further, a good guide for using this API can be found [here](https://techtutorialsx.com/2017/07/01/esp32-arduino-controlling-a-buzzer-with-pwm/).